# Using DynamoDB transact_write_items how to update multiple items of a table using Composite primary key?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, boto3, dynamodb-queries

I want to update multiple items in the table based on conditions of primary key and sort key. Is it possible to achieve this using transact_write_items?
I have a table with Primary key as `p_name` and sort key as `a_id`. I would have to update `a_status` to **active** if `a_id = a_id1` , else will need to update `a_status` to **inactive** for any other value of `a_id`.

```
response = dynamo_client.transact_write_items(
    TransactItems=[
        {
            'Update': {
                'TableName': 'table-1',
                'Key': {
                    'p_name': {
                        'S': 'pName'
                    },
                    'a_id': {
                        'S': 'a_id1'
                    }
                },
                'ConditionExpression': 'a_id = :a_id',
                'UpdateExpression': 'set a_status = :aStatus'
                'ExpressionAttributeNames': {
                    ':a_id': {'S': 'a_id1'},
                    ':aStatus': {'S': 'active'}
                }
            },
            'Update': {
                'TableName': 'table-1',
                'Key': {
                    'p_name': {
                        'S': 'pName'
                    },
                    'a_id': {
                        'S': 'a_id1'
                    }
                },
                'ConditionExpression': 'a_id <> :a_id',
                'UpdateExpression': 'set a_status = :aStatus'
                'ExpressionAttributeNames': {
                    ':a_id': {'S': 'a_id1'},
                    ':aStatus': {'S': 'inactive'}
                }
            }
        }
    ]
)
```

This throws the following error:

`An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the TransactWriteItems operation: Transaction request cannot include multiple operations on one item`.

However, as I wanted to update all the items which does not have `a_id` as `a_id1` to **inactive** as part of second update call, I could not query it for a particular `a_id` as I would not know what other ids would exist.

**Note**: All the `a_id` values (sort key values)  begin with `a_id` and would be in form of `a_id1`, `a_id2`, `a_id3` and so on.  Was there any way to handle this using `transact_write_items` where in we can query based on primary key alone? Or if there was a way we can filter sort key based on `begins_with` within `transact_write_items`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should put your Update to seperate objects like this:

```
response = dynamo_client.transact_write_items(
TransactItems=[
    {
        'Update': {
            'TableName': 'table-1',
            'Key': {
                'p_name': {
                    'S': 'pName'
                },
                'a_id': {
                    'S': 'a_id1'
                }
            },
            'ConditionExpression': 'a_id = :a_id',
            'UpdateExpression': 'set a_status = :aStatus'
            'ExpressionAttributeNames': {
                ':a_id': {'S': 'a_id1'},
                ':aStatus': {'S': 'active'}
            }
        }
    },
    {
        'Update': {
            'TableName': 'table-1',
            'Key': {
                'p_name': {
                    'S': 'pName'
                },
                'a_id': {
                    'S': 'a_id1'
                }
            },
            'ConditionExpression': 'a_id <> :a_id',
            'UpdateExpression': 'set a_status = :aStatus'
            'ExpressionAttributeNames': {
                ':a_id': {'S': 'a_id1'},
                ':aStatus': {'S': 'inactive'}
            }
        }
    }
])
```